# Pandas dataframe auto-reset while running the program

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extracting some data from multiple `.txt` file and store them to a pandas dataframe line by line. However, the program shows me that the dataframe removes all previous data after number of lines reaches three like the following shows:

```
   Col A     Col B
0  979.9065  0.0012
1  649.9995  8.301
2  -1.3696   -5.98

   Col A     Col B
0  932.0005  0.0037
```

And I need the dataframe to be like this:

```
  Col A     Col B
0  979.9065  0.0012
1  649.9995  8.301
2  -1.3696   -5.98
3  932.0005  0.0037
```

The following is my code to construct the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['ColA', 'ColB'])
with open('C:/Users/chent/Desktop/Device_Test/' + file, "r", ) as curr_file:
      content = curr_file.readlines()                   
      count = 0
                    
     #the next line of the line with "V(Status)" 
     # is the target line
      for val in content:
          if val.find("V(Status)")==-1:
               count+=1
          else:
               count+=1                           
               line = content[count]
                            
               #parse the target line
               TESTDATA = list(line.split())

               #convert data to dataframe
               curr_V = TESTDATA[0]
               curr_I = TESTDATA[1]
               TEST_V = StringIO(curr_V)
               TEST_I = StringIO(curr_I)
               df = df.append({'V' : curr_V, 'I' : curr_I}, ignore_index = True)
#empty the folder
file_list = glob.glob('C:/Users/chent/Desktop/Device_Test/*')
      for f in file_list:
          os.remove(f)
```

What part am I supposed to change in order to get the result I desried?

Update: Oops, I forgot to include part of code of removing files (cuz names of `.txt` files I am intending to reach are the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you put all of the text files that you want to read in that folder, you can use:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
files = glob.glob('C:/Users/chent/Desktop/Device_Test/*')
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in files]).reset_index(drop=True)
df
```

You can go a step further and create an extra column to show you the name of the file for each row, which can be helpful. NOTE: you must change the filepath `'Desktop/testfile*'` as I have used my own.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
files = glob.glob('Desktop/testfile*')
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f).assign(filename=os.path.basename(f)) for f in files]).reset_index(drop=True)
df

Out[1]: 
      Col A   Col B       filename
0  979.9065  0.0012  testfile1.txt
1  649.9995  8.3010  testfile1.txt
2   -1.3696 -5.9800  testfile1.txt
3  932.0005  0.0037  testfile2.txt
```